# Is it possible to delete commit reference from github issue?

Tags: github

I deleted all commits from a public repository. But I found that some commits are still available by commit reference in issues. Is it possible to delete commit reference from github issue without deleting an issue?

Comment: “I deleted all commits from a public repository.” Commits cannot really be deleted, so how exactly did you do that? Why not just delete the whole repo if the goal is to destroy the data?

Comment: @matt, I want to keep repo for issues and leave all issues for history.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by request to GitHub support. They cleaned the cache on their side and the references on commits have gone from issues.